# Is it possible to use a Docker Container as a repository for a static Java library?

Tags: java, docker, artifacts

**Situation**: I've recently started work as an Automation Engineer at a new company.  The company's philosophy is to dockerize everything, which is great.  I am creating a new Java-based test framework that all of our down-stream test projects will depend on for pulling in common code, managing test tool versions, etc., using Gradle to produce a static Java JAR library.  This is something I've done at several companies before with some success.

**Problem**: The company's chief architect wants me to dockerize the JAR file that is produced and use that container/image as the dependency for the down-stream Java-based test projects, instead of storing it in a typical static-library-repo like CodeArtifact/Artifactory/etc.  The image would be versioned in our Docker image repo.

**Question**: Is it possible to do this, without adding a file-server app to the container?

*I don't believe it to be a good idea, even if it works, because we're adding complexity wrapped around a simple jar that could be stored in a static file artifact server like AWS CodeArtifact (we're on AWS already), although I will take any differing opinions under advisement, if offered.  Maybe I'm just missing something here and I can't see out of the box I've always used...*

Comment: I agree with you assesment.

Comment: I assume that he means that you're producing an image with the library already installed, and then other Dockerfiles can use that image in their `FROM` attribute - not that the image would be useful by itself.

Comment: My guess is the Architect wants you to build a custom Test Container that can easily be spun up in testing scenarios (which may or may not be Java based) - https://www.testcontainers.org/

Comment: @NickODell I think that's the part I wasn't understanding, thank you.  I've used docker a lot for running the actual tests, but not for library management.

Comment: @DanW Yes, that's the case, and I understand that part, but what I'm talking about isn't the test project, it's the framework that the test projects use.